# Create a dataframe with a reserved word as column name

Tags: r, dataframe, reserved-words

I tried the 2 ways below and it seems that whatever I do, a dot is added at the end of the name of the column "repeat":

```
df <- data.frame(col1=1:5,col2=6:10,"repeat"=11:15)

df <- data.frame(col1=1:5,col2=6:10,`repeat`=11:15)

df
```

[image]

Is there a way to do force it?
Thanks!

Comment: `data.frame` has an argument, `check.names = FALSE`. But there are often good reasons when R tries to enforce something.

Comment: thanks @neilfws! I'm well aware I'll run into other issues later by doing this. but for today that'll do the trick.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After inspecting `> data.frame`, I found the solution (avoid that the names are checked):

```
df <- data.frame(col1=1:5,col2=6:10, 'repeat' = 11:15, check.names=FALSE)
df
##   col1 col2 repeat
## 1    1    6     11
## 2    2    7     12
## 3    3    8     13
## 4    4    9     14
## 5    5   10     15
```

An alternative is renaming of the wrongly named df:

```
df <- data.frame(col1=1:5,col2=6:10, "repeat" = 11:15)
names(df) <- c("col1", "col2", "repeat")
df
##   col1 col2 repeat
## 1    1    6     11
## 2    2    7     12
## 3    3    8     13
## 4    4    9     14
## 5    5   10     15
```